# How to cross SUM with COUNT of fields containing an integer inside parentheses?

Tags: excel

So I have a few cells with a numeric value in parentheses. I'd like to count how many times each fruit occurs (apples, oranges, bananas) but also count the values in the parentheses as a sum. How would I go about this?

[image: I've included an image of what I'd be trying to do.]

Comment: What have you tried? Is your data exactly like this, or is it possible to have say "Banana (6) (Green)"?  Can you edit the data/use a helper column?

Answer (score 3):

in D1:

```
=SUM(($A$1:$A$12=C1)+((LEFT($A$1:$A$12,LEN(C1))=C1)*IFERROR(--MID($A$1:$A$12,FIND("(",$A$1:$A$12)+1,FIND(")",$A$1:$A$12)-FIND("(",$A$1:$A$12)-1),0)))
```

Array formula So confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]